# Angular js http get parse.com image url

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform

I'm using parse api with angular js, so far so good except when I try printing image or in the console log I get [Object Object], how do I get the image url

The item.product_image isn't a file url...somebody help!!!

Comment: Can you please provide some example code to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: just solved it, was a product_image.url I didn't catch that 'url' bit